# Response.Headers and IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, http-headers, integrated-pipeline-mode

So I'm trying to iterate over Response.Headers for a custom caching job, but I'm getting the following error when I touch the thing:

```
This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode
```

It this possible to do in IIS6? Is there a workaround?

```
var allHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers;  
// error thrown as soon as it's accessed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot access the HTTP response headers unless you are running in integrated mode because they are sent by the server at a later stage of the execution of the request when running in standard mode.

Comment: +1 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx