# How to check if HttpContext.Current.Response have an existing Header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, http-headers

I was working on a scenario where I have to add header to the Response Header.

I added a Response Header like this:-
`HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("key1", "value1")`

After some functional flow I required to add value to same **"key1"**: `HttpContext.Current.Reponse.AddHeader("key1, "value2")`

thus value in Response Headers look like this:-
**key1** : **value1, value2**

I want to avoid the **value2** addition to the same keyword **key1**.

How to go about this?

I tried:-

```
If HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers("key1") Then
    HttpContext.Current.Reponse.AddHeader("key1, "value2")
EndIf
```

But I got the error: **This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode** at `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers("key1")`

I have IIS6 running.
This http://forums.asp.net/post/2676139.aspx says that it doestn't works if its not IIS7

Please help if I can do it in IIS6. Thanks,

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269261/response-headers-and-iis6

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if it haskeys using this line

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.HasKeys()
```

so in your example you would do like so

```
If Not HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.HasKeys() Then
    HttpContext.Current.Reponse.AddHeader("key1, "value2")
EndIf
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers` It self is throwing "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode" exception. so it wont go till HasKeys

Comment: Well I guess you could configure IIS, here's a tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cek8kw6e.aspx